# stackoverflow search api

Tags: c#, json, stackexchange-api

I would like to use the search method of stackoverflow API to return the json structure of results based on a search keyword and then display those results (title, description and the url) in the SearchResults div.

I am new to C# and my first attempt went something like this:

```
    protected void searchStockOverflow(string y)
    {

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?intitle="+y);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{ \"intitle\": \"" + y + "\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            SearchResults.InnerHtml += "<div style='border:1px solid blue;margin:5px;'>";
            SearchResults.InnerHtml += responseText + "<br />";
            SearchResults.InnerHtml += "</div><br style='clear:both;' />";
        }
    }
```

The issue is that what is returned looks like dingbats rubbish - i guess because it is serialized and need to be deserialized?

Comment: most probably you need to change the encoding of the string

Comment: There is a typo in your function name: searchStockOverflow :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would definitely say consider using the REST client; however, to look at the issues... generally you want to deserialize the data as JSON manually, *then* run that data through your UI code. For example:

```
static void SearchStackOverflow(string y)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?intitle=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(y));
    httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string responseText;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    var result = (SearchResult)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(responseText, typeof(SearchResult));
    .... do something with result ...
}
class SearchResult
{
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}
class Question
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int answer_count { get; set; }
}
```

Which uses the JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Extensions.dll

Comment: +1 for JSON deserialization and a other fixes (URL string escaping, GET vs POST). But I don't think that `AutomaticDecompression` is needed, since there is no `Accept-Encoding` field specified in the HTTP header (i.e. in `httpWebRequest`).

Comment: @Groo - yes, but if I post a SO API example that doesn't use compression, I'm pretty sure my colleagues will laugh at me (considering where I work, etc). And adding the support also adds the request headers (I checked in fiddler)

Answer (score 3):

Also Take a look at [Stacky StackApps .Net Client Library](http://stacky.codeplex.com/) which is REST-based API that provides access to stackoverflow family of websites.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm on my Mac and can't run a test on your code. You might want to check the character encoding of both your page and the response stream coming back. If they don't match; it could cause the characters coming from the response stream to be rendered incorrectly, hence the rubbish you're seeing.